# react-native-dropdown-select-list cant apply dropdownShown={true}

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I'm creating a dropdown list in an android app with react native that should render already opened.

But if I add the dropdownShown={true} it will only render a line. If at runtime I change the value to false, reload the app, and change it back to true, the list renders as I intended.
I imagine that the component is trying to open before being completely assembled, but honestly I'm not sure of anything because I don't know much about react native, can anyone give me an idea of ​​how to solve this?
This is my code so far:

````
const [isPickerVisible, setIsPickerVisible] = useState(false);
    const [selectedMonth, setSelectedMonth] = useState("abril");
    const items = [
        { key: 'Janeiro', value: 'Janeiro' },
        { key: 'Fevereiro', value: 'Fevereiro' },
        { key: 'Março', value: 'Março' },
        { key: 'Abril', value: 'Abril' },
        { key: 'Maio', value: 'Maio' },
        { key: 'Junho', value: 'Junho' },
        { key: 'Agosto', value: 'Agosto' },
        { key: 'Setembro', value: 'Setembro' },
        { key: 'Outubro', value: 'Outubro' },
        { key: 'Novembro', value: 'Novembro' },
        { key: 'Dezembro', value: 'Dezembro' },
    ];
    const handleOpenMenu = () => {
        setIsPickerVisible(false);
    };
    const handleSelect = (value) => {
        setSelectedMonth(value);

    };
    return (
        <>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsPickerVisible(true)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Despesas {selectedMonth}</Text>
                <Icon name={'calendar-search'} style={styles.icon} />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            {isPickerVisible && (
                <SelectList
                   setSelected={(val) => handleSelect(val)}
                    onSelect={() => handleOpenMenu()}
                    data={items}
                    search={false}
                    boxStyles={styles.container}
                    dropdownStyles={styles.dropContainer}
                    dropdownShown={true} 
                    
                />
            )}
        </>

    );


}```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display: 'none'
    },

    dropContainer: {
        position: 'relative',
        width: 110,
        borderRadius: 0,
        left: 270,
        zIndex: 999999,
        top: -30
    },
    button: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 10,
    },
    icon: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 20
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});
export default DropDownList;
````